# Reloading view after search crashes the app

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm making an app that has a view with `UITableView` with `UISearchDisplayController`. Data comes from `NSFetchedResultsController`. All is working fine: I get the data, table view is being populated, search works great. The only problem is that if I search and then click on "Cancel"(without deleting the text from the UISearchBar) and then go back to previous view controller and then go to that same view with `UITableView` and `UISearchDisplayController` it crashes with this being written to the log:

> 2012-01-06 16:46:37.559 MyApp[9586:207] *** -[SomeRandomViewController
>   controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance
>   0x778d060

I've googled and stackoverflowed for that error, tried to release `NSFetchedResultsController` variable, did set it and its' delegate to nil, but nothing helps.

And if I do some search, then delete the text from the search bar and then tap on "Back" and go back to that view it works just fine.

A bit of the code:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

  self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
  self.searchFetchedRC = nil;
  [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {

  self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
  [self fetchedResultsController];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = @"";
  self.searchDisplayController.active = NO;
  [self searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:self.searchDisplayController];
  return YES;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

**Update**

Without zombies the output to the log is:

> 2012-01-09 09:25:48.128 Butane[17325:207]
>   -[UITextMagnifierTimeWeightedPoint controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8251dc0

**Update 2**

Dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [self.mySearchDisplayController release];
  self.mySearchDisplayController.delegate = nil;
  self.mySearchDisplayController = nil;
  [self.fetchedResultsController release];
  self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
  self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
  [self.searchFetchedRC release];
  self.searchFetchedRC.delegate = nil;
  self.searchFetchedRC = nil;
  [self.tableView release];
  [textView release];
  self.tableView = nil;
  self.tableView.delegate = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}

mySearchDisplayController = UISearchDisplayController

fetchedResultsController and searchFetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsControllers

tableView = UITableView

textView = [HPGrowingTextView][1]
```

**Update 3**

Inspired by the answer of Tia I've set FRCs and their delegates to nil in `searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch` method. Works so far so good

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {

  self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
  self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
  self.searchFetchedRC.delegate = nil;
  self.searchFetchedRC = nil;
  [self fetchedResultsController];
}
```

Comment: [Enable zombies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) and get back to us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532861/core-data-app-crashing-with-controllerwillchangecontent-unrecognized-selector won't help?

Comment: @tia thanks for the link, but it doesn't help

Comment: @Joe updated question for what happens without zombies(they were enabled)

Comment: I don't see your `dealloc`. Do you release the controller there?

Comment: @tia question updated. I think I do release it. It does look kinda sloppy, but I'm quite new to iOS development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)dealloc {
  //[self.mySearchDisplayController release];
  self.mySearchDisplayController.delegate = nil;
  self.mySearchDisplayController = nil;
  //[self.fetchedResultsController release];
  self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
  self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
  //[self.searchFetchedRC release];
  self.searchFetchedRC.delegate = nil;
  self.searchFetchedRC = nil;
  //[self.tableView release];
  [textView release];
  self.tableView.delegate = nil;
  self.tableView = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

You are over-releasing your properties, as setting it to `nil` already release it for retained properties. I tried to remove extra releasing code by commenting them out, so please try to replace your dealloc with my code above and see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still the same: 2012-01-09 10:46:01.154 MyApp[19078:207] *** -[SomeRandomViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7790820

Comment: Inspired by your answer I did set NSFetchedResultsControllers and their delegates to nil in searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch method. Up to now it's working. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction :)

Comment: No worries, but you should really study the document about memory management as it is quite fundamentally crucial for iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as my VC implemented the UISearchBarDelegate protocol and searchBarTextDidEndEditing: was being called *after* I'd dismissed the VC in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.

I fixed it with:

```
self.searchDisplayController.delegate=nil;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate=nil;
```

before the

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```