# Swift: NSArrayM controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my controller I have **two** `UICollectionView`'s with two different `NSFetchedResultsControllers`:

This is how I create it in `viewDidLoad:`:

```
private func setupFetchedResultsControllers() {

    let currentStudent = BWSettings.sharedSettings.currentUser as! BWCoreDataStudent
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()

    let topFetchReguest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BWCoreDataWishlistBook")
    let positionDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "position", ascending: true)

    topFetchReguest.sortDescriptors = [positionDescriptor]

    topFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: topFetchReguest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    topFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "student.id = %lld AND position != nil", currentStudent.id)
    topFetchedResultsController.delegate = BWStudentWishlistFetchedResultsControllerDelegate(collectionView: topCollectionView, studentWishlistContainerViewController: self)

    try! topFetchedResultsController.performFetch()

    let bottomFetchReguest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BWCoreDataWishlistBook")
    let addedAtDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

    bottomFetchReguest.sortDescriptors = [addedAtDescriptor]

    bottomFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: bottomFetchReguest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    bottomFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "student.id = %lld AND position = nil", currentStudent.id)
    bottomFetchedResultsController.delegate = BWStudentWishlistFetchedResultsControllerDelegate(collectionView: bottomCollectionView, studentWishlistContainerViewController: self)

    try! bottomFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
}
```

And this is my custom delegate:

```
class BWStudentWishlistFetchedResultsControllerDelegate: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var collectionViewChanges = [[NSFetchedResultsChangeType: [NSIndexPath]]]()

    private weak var studentWishlistContainerViewController: BWStudentWishlistContainerViewController!

    init(collectionView: UICollectionView, studentWishlistContainerViewController: BWStudentWishlistContainerViewController) {

        self.collectionView = collectionView
        self.studentWishlistContainerViewController = studentWishlistContainerViewController
    }

    //MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    //here are my custom default methods
}
```

This is a whole error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM controllerWillChangeContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ec0d930'

Why it happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532861/core-data-app-crashing-with-controllerwillchangecontent-unrecognized-selector?rq=1

Comment: I read this question, but what is the solution actually? Additionally there is **Objective-C** lanaguge, and here is **Swift**.

Comment: You are using `try!`. Since that did not work, try using *try catch blocks*, so the app would not crash but throw an exception, which has more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that your NSFetchedResultsController delegate is deallocating. 
Instead of :

```
 topFetchedResultsController.delegate = BWStudentWishlistFetchedResultsControllerDelegate(collectionView: topCollectionView, studentWishlistContainerViewController: self)
```

You need to keep a reference to the delegate using a property :

```
var fetchDelegate = BWStudentWishlistFetchedResultsControllerDelegate(..)
...
topFetchedResultsController.delegate = self.fetchDelegate
```

With your way of doing this the delegate is released at the end of **setupFetchedResultsControllers()** scope